# Lookup collect all addresses for host

Tags: ansible

In a template, I am currently doing something like:

```
vader = "{ {{ lookup('dig', 'vader', qtype='A') }}, {{ lookup('dig', 'vader', qtype='AAAA') }} }"
```

to get something like

```
vader = "{ 1.1.1.1, a:a:a::1}"
```

I'd like to improve it in the following way:

- Handle cases when there is no ipv4 or ipv6 address (now it outputs `"{ a.b.c.d, }"` if there is no ipv6 for example)
- Handle cases when there is more than one address
- Make a macro or a way to call it with a shorter syntax, like `vader = {{ resolve("vader") }}` or something

Using the provided answer I was able to get to this:

```
{% macro ips(hostname) -%} "{ {{ (q('community.general.dig', hostname) + q('community.general.dig', hostname, qtype='AAAA')) | select | join(', ') }} }" {% endmacro -%}
```

Which I can call in my `pf.conf` with:

```
myhost = {{ ips("myhost") }}
```

Comment: Please do not add solutions as an edit to your question. Provide a self answer and make it complete. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Use `query` (shortcut `q`) rather than `lookup` to force returning a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true). In that case you will get a list for all `A` and `AAAA` entries which you just have to add together.

Since any query without results will return a list with a single empty string element, it is very easy to clean-up with the `select` filter.

Regarding the "macro" I don't really get it as this is not an Ansible concept (are you referring to a Jinja2 macro you would use in a full blown template?). I did my best in the below example to make things reusable.

Moreover, I'm not sure I'm meeting the target as none of your examples are actually valid (it's not yaml nor ini and it's neither list nor dicts....) so I took for granted you wanted a list in the end

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This is your list of IPs for a given fqdn currated from empty results
    my_ip_list: "{{ q('community.general.dig', fqdn) + q('community.general.dig', fqdn, qtype='AAAA') | select }}"
    # This is the fqdn used if you don't override it in your task
    fqdn: aws.com

  tasks:
    - name: Show result with default fqdn
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_ip_list

    - name: Show result overriding the fqdn for a list of results
      vars:
        fqdn: "{{ item }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: my_ip_list
      loop:
        - lesziconofages.org
        - laposte.fr
        - smile.eu
```

gives as result:

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show result with default fqdn] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_ip_list": [
        "3.162.38.45",
        "3.162.38.44",
        "3.162.38.101",
        "3.162.38.96",
        "2600:9000:262a:200:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:ca00:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:4a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:7600:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:de00:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:5a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:9600:10:ef80:1740:93a1",
        "2600:9000:262a:c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1"
    ]
}

TASK [Show result overriding the fqdn for a list of results] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=lesziconofages.org) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "lesziconofages.org",
    "my_ip_list": [
        "213.186.33.24",
        "2001:41d0:1:1b00:213:186:33:24"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=laposte.fr) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "laposte.fr",
    "my_ip_list": [
        "178.213.66.103"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=smile.eu) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "smile.eu",
    "my_ip_list": [
        "145.239.192.138"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

***Forward note***: if for whatever reason you really need to output the result as a comma separated list of elements surrounded by single curly braces, it's quite easy to adapt the above (example for default fqdn only, adapt to your needs):

```yaml
    - name: output exactly as in question
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ '{' ~ my_ip_list | join(', ') ~ '}' }}"
```

=>

```
TASK [output exactly as in question] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{3.162.38.44, 3.162.38.96, 3.162.38.45, 3.162.38.101, 2600:9000:262a:fc00:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:6c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:a400:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:e400:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:e600:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:7000:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1, 2600:9000:262a:d400:10:ef80:1740:93a1}"
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that it was in a template, and that syntax is pf.conf syntax. What I meant by macro is to be able to call it in a short way in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Declare lists of hostnames and types you want to create macro(s) for. For example,

```yaml
hnames: [aws.com, example.com]
qtypes: [A, AAAA]
```

*dig* the data

```yaml
  ips: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for hname in hnames %}
    {{ hname }}:
    {% for qtype in qtypes %}
      {{ qtype }}: {{ lookup('dig', hname, qtype=qtype)|split(',') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

Note: Any lookup plugin runs always on the controller, not on the remote hosts.

---

gives

```yaml
  ips:
    aws.com:
      A:
      - 18.66.26.47
      - 18.66.26.114
      - 18.66.26.93
      - 18.66.26.77
      AAAA:
      - 2600:9000:2304:a000:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:3a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:2200:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:4e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:3400:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:4400:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:3c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1
      - 2600:9000:2304:7c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1
    example.com:
      A:
      - 93.184.216.34
      AAAA:
      - 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

In your case, you want CSV all IPs

```yaml
  ips_all_csv: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for hname,attr in ips.items() %}
    {{ hname }}: {{ attr|json_query('*')|flatten|join(',') }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  ips_all_csv:
    aws.com: 18.66.26.114,18.66.26.93,18.66.26.47,18.66.26.77,2600:9000:2304:7c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:2200:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:a000:10:ef80:1740:93a1
    example.com: 93.184.216.34,2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```

Test the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for hname in hnames %}
          {{ hname }} = "{ {{ ips_all_csv[hname] }} }"
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    aws.com = "{ 18.66.26.93,18.66.26.47,18.66.26.77,18.66.26.114,2600:9000:2304:4400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:7c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:a000:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:2200:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1 }"
    example.com = "{ 93.184.216.34,2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 }"
```

If this is what you want create the template

```yaml
shell> cat pf.conf.j2 
# macros
{% for hname in hnames %}
{{ hname }} = "{ {{ ips_all_csv[hname] }} }"
{% endfor %}
```

and write the files

```yaml
    - template:
        src: pf.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/pf.conf
```

gives (for remote hosts test_11 and test_13)

```ini
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat /tmp/pf.conf
# macros
aws.com = "{ 18.66.26.77,18.66.26.93,18.66.26.114,18.66.26.47,2600:9000:2304:3400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:2200:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:a000:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:7c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1 }"
example.com = "{ 93.184.216.34,2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 }"
```

```ini
shell> ssh admin@test_13 cat /tmp/pf.conf
# macros
aws.com = "{ 18.66.26.77,18.66.26.93,18.66.26.114,18.66.26.47,2600:9000:2304:3400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4400:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:2200:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:4e00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:7c00:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:a000:10:ef80:1740:93a1,2600:9000:2304:3a00:10:ef80:1740:93a1 }"
example.com = "{ 93.184.216.34,2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946 }"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hnames: [aws.com, example.com]
    qtypes: [A, AAAA]

    ips: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for hname in hnames %}
      {{ hname }}:
      {% for qtype in qtypes %}
        {{ qtype }}: {{ lookup('dig', hname, qtype=qtype)|split(',') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    ips_all_csv: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for hname,attr in ips.items() %}
      {{ hname }}: {{ attr|json_query('*')|flatten|join(',') }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ips
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        var: ips_all_csv
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for hname in hnames %}
          {{ hname }} = "{ {{ ips_all_csv[hname] }} }"
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true

    - template:
        src: pf.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/pf.conf
```